# How to get rid of 0s and NaN in Series.value_counts?

Tags: python, pandas

If have a df with several columns where cell values can be 0, 1, 3, 4, 5 as well as nan.

Column 2:

```
[4, 4, 3, 2, 4, 4, 5, 2, 4, 3, 2, 3, 2, 5, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 3, 4, 3, 5, 5, 5, 4, 5, 4, 2, 4, 2, 5, 4, 3, 1, 4, 4, 3, 3, 5, 3, 3, 3, 5, 3, 5, 4, 3, 5, 4, 4, 5, 4, 2, 1, 4, 3, 5, 4, 0, 0]
```

Column 3

```
[4, 4, 5, 4, 5, 4, 5, 5, 5, 4, 3, 4, 5, 4, 4, 3, 5, 5, 5, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4, 5, 3, 5, 4, 4, 2, 5, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 5, 0, 0]
```

I would like to create a table that give me value counts of each of this rows. This is what I did:

```
df.apply(pd.Series.value_counts). reset_index()
```

I don't want 0s and NaN to be counted, what do I do? Also, can I get percentages instead of numbers?

I tried to add dropna=True and normalize=True in the brackets, resulting in this error message:

```
value_counts() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

This might be an alternative way to reach my desired output, but still needs to be filtered for 0s and NaN:

```
df1 = (df.melt('column1')
         .pivot_table(index='variable',
                      columns='value',
                      aggfunc='size',
                    )   
         .rename_axis(index=None, columns=None))
```

Comment: Can you add some data values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you need replace `0` to `NaN`s and use [`value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) with `normalize=True` per `axis=0`:

```
df1 = df.replace(0, np.nan).apply(pd.value_counts, normalize=True)
```

If need per `axis=1`:

```
df2 = df.replace(0, np.nan).apply(pd.value_counts, normalize=True, axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

To get rid of NuNs:

```
df = df['name_of_column'].dropna()
```

To get rid of 0s:

```
data = ds.loc[ds['name_of_column'] != 0]
```